# How to update individual element in javascript only depending on service response

Tags: javascript, timer, return-value, onload, auto-update

I would like to update a value inside a row, I don't want to use OnReload because that uploads the whole script and it is depending of a timer ex: reload this every 5 seconds ... it is not what I want. Unless there is something modern that I could use for this purpose.
Not sure, what could trigger this update and how to make this script?
For example: if item.updatelabel.value is different from the service response then update item.updatelabel with new value

```
<script>
        fetch("http:myservice").then(res => res.json()).then(serviceResponse => {
            let newdoc = '';
            for (const item of serviceResponse) {
                newdoc += `
                    <div class="1">
                       <p id="name" class="title-text  ">${item.id}</p>
                      <h2 id="id" class="updatelabel-text">${item.updatelabel}</h2>(** This is the only thing to update)
                      <p class="small-text ">some fancy text</p>
                     </div>
                `
            }
            document.querySelector('.myclass').innerHTML = newdoc;
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: if no jquery .  you may try this https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript/     as there is no proper trigger. when page load complete

Comment: How would it be using jquery?

Comment: how do the fetch happen in intervals? is it ajax?

Comment: @zod . not intervals yet but Im open to ideas. all I have is what you see on my snippet. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call an ajax in certain intervals and , inside the call back of the ajax replace the text

```
function fetchdata(){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'fetch.php',
  type: 'post',
  success: function(response){
   // Perform operation on the return value
    if($conditionsatisfy){
            document.querySelector('.myclass').innerHTML = newdoc;

  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(fetchdata,5000);
});
```

Comment: give dynamic id for class or id like class="updatelabel-text-i" to identify that and replace using .html

Comment: I was able to use your logic. Thanks. I didn't use ajax because it had to be done in JS only. but the idea was perfect for what I need it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I need a little more  information for your  question.

**How could item.updatelabel.value be different if Its getting the render data from serivce response ?**

you wrote  "if item.updatelabel.value is different from the service response then update item" ? . It appears To be an Array of items, and the value rendered is a string. so are your trying to say "if any of the items are changed after the API call to call the API again or you have hard coded items and want to update them from an API call ?

When you say "update that item" do you mean make another API request or change the state of the application page ?

Comment: Yes. exactly that. I will have to go and refresh to always be getting new data. but if I use that onload it will be refreshing the script every 2 seconds and it will be always blinking. that's why I want to try to -1) make another call - get the data 2) only refresh updatelabel-so after the second call, do not update everything inside the script only the row.

Answer (score 0):

So Now that I understand you correctly you could have some condition as above and keep calling. **I think what your best solution for this would be is  Web Sockets.** 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

With Websockets you can have a realtime connection between the client and the server. Check out https://socket.io/ makes working with it easy. Like a news feed or Instagram the page will update and function as requested. It will update the items. real time without any need for reload.

Also With your API reuqest you can greatly improve the readability with ES7

```
 const getData = async () => {
    //fetching data 
    let data = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    //converting to json 
    let json = await data.json()
    console.log(json)

    let serviceResponse = json
     //do logic or return data here
 }

  getData()
```

Comment: I see. WebSockets are awsome. but all I need to update is this  <h2 id="id" class="updatelabel-text">${item.updatelabel}</h2>(** This is the only thing to update) .Thank you for your responses .